# Watch an API for Updates

Tags: node.js, webhooks

I am trying to make an API watch to `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest`
and detect if any  changes so I can update my clients just like a web hook notification. But what am doing is

```js
while(true){
    fetch(https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest)
    .then(res => ......
}
```

I am caching the  result and  always check if there is any changes, If there is, I will send a request to the client.
I am looking for a **better** way to pull the data  instead of making a while loops

Comment: You should consider using `setInterval()`- https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args

Comment: If you are only able to get the the URL instead of subscribing for updates (pull vs push) then you don't really have much choices. Although it could be done better than a `while` loop.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev Setting interval may cause a little problem  because if dollar falls and rise between the time interval, its a big folk to  my target

Comment: This while loop is blocking your node process, and makes many many requests... probably not the best approach, dollar is changing (even in the exchange)  every X sec make an interval with the same X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `while` loop, you would potentially send many requests before one returns. And even when one returns, it's not going to necessarily be in order. Here is a quick example of what might happen if there is a network spike for example:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,  ms));

async function mockNetworkCall(num) { 
  const timings = [50, 150, 50]
  console.log(`sending request ${num}`);
  await sleep(timings[num]);
  
  console.log(`request ${num} finished`)
}


for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  mockNetworkCall(i);
}
```

You could avoid the `while` loop if you instead take the approach to only do a new request when the last one finishes. In that case, you will only have a single request active at any one time and you know that you're getting the result in order.

You can wrap the logic for that in a simple function to watch a URL and only re-initiate a request when the previous one is finished. This is the skeleton for such a function - it might need tweaking according to your needs:

```js
function watch({ url, retryCount, lastResponse = null}) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => { 
      
      /* do something */
      
      return res;
    })
    .then(res => watch({url, retryCount, lastResponse: res})) //launch again
    .catch(err => { 
      /* handle error */ 
      console.error("error getting URL", err);
      console.warn("retries left: ", retryCount);
      
      if (retryCount-- > 0) {
        watch({url, retryCount, lastResponse});
      }
    })
}

watch({url: "google.com", retryCount: 3});
```

Or the same using `async/await`

```js
async function watch({ url, retryCount, lastResponse = null}) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);

    /* do something */
    
    watch({url, retryCount, lastResponse: res}); //launch again
  } catch (err) {
    /* handle error */ 
    console.error("error getting URL", err);
    console.warn("retries left: ", retryCount);
      
    if (retryCount-- > 0) {
      watch({url, retryCount, lastResponse});
    }
  }
}

watch({url: "google.com", retryCount: 3});
```